# Explain the values returned by readNetFromCaffe's forward method

Tags: python, opencv, caffe, face-detection

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt, model)
detections = net.forward()
```

The detections will have 4D array with shape (1, 1, 200, 7). What are the different values there?

```
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
```

The above loop gets confidence value at the 3rd dimension provide is for row number and 4th dimension is the column number, so it is pretty much clear that the object is detected with that much confidence or probability. But I could't understand the other parameters.

```
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
```

to create a box, the above code is used with 3 to 6 columns and its values. So what are these values in columns 2 to 6?

Below code to reproduce the values...

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import imutils
import numpy as np
import cv2
import argparse
import time

# construct the argument parser
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True, help="path to caffe deploy prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, help="path to pre-trained caffe model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5, help="minimum confidence required")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# MODEL - load the model which will be used to predict
print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

# INPUT - start video to capture frames
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
# vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()  # this is to stream video for Raspberry Pi camera
# vs = FileVideoStream(path='/path to file')  # this is to get video content from file
time.sleep(2)  # allow the cam to warm up

# for live streaming, while loop will be required to capture frames
while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

    # get the dimensions of the frame
    print('shape of frame:', frame.shape)
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]

    # blob the frame
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, scalefactor=1.0,
                                 size=(300, 300), mean=(104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    # use the blob for detection
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()
    print(detections)
    # loop over the detections
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
        if confidence < args['confidence']:
            continue

        # create box
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

        # draw the box on the face
        text = "{:.2f}%".format(confidence * 100)
        y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
        cv2.putText(frame, text, (startX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # show on screen
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

the first column represents the class id to which it belongs
the second column represents the confidence value, is there any object in the frame or not by comparing it with confidence threshold
[3:7] i.e. 3,4,5,6 columns represents the coordinates/points to create a box around the object, they are stored as numpy array hence to be converted in int type to make a box.